# Process not found in power-shell script checking msiexec is ready for another installation

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

```
$check = Get-Process -Name 'msiexec' 

if($check -eq $null)
{
    Write-Host 'ready for installation'
}

else
{
    Write-Host 'waiting for completion of current process'
    Sleep(10)

    if($check -eq $null)
    {
        Write-Host 'ready for installation'
    }

    else
    {
        Write-Host 'stopping the process'
       Stop-Process -Name 'msiexec' -Force
    }

 }
```

So in above Code for 1st line it is giving error object not found because msiexec is not running when no installation is going on so how handle that in try & catch

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
try 
{
  $check = Get-process -Name "msiexec" -erroraction STOP
}
catch
{
  # Here will be the statements which should be executed after the error is caught.
}
```

Comment: ok I have one more question I want to check condition weather process 'msiexec' is in ideal or not how to check it. As after completion of installation msiexec is going in ideal state for same time so i want to checked that can any one help me?

Comment: @vip You could check if ["_MSIExecute" mutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/-msiexecute-mutex) exists.